# Able to cast away constness using static_cast why?

Tags: c++

We know that using static_cast we can not remove the constness from an expression. But today i came across one scenario where i am able to do it. I am not able to figure out how it actually works. Please find below the code. This code compiles without any error and gives the correct result.

why this code does not give any error ?

```
void func1(double *ptr) 
{
  cout<<*ptr;
}
void main()
{
  const double ab=2;
  func1(&static_cast<double>(ab));//I put & operator infront of static_cast and this works. 
  cin.get();
}
```

Comment: The fact that compiles and runs makes me question your compiler. `void main()` is nonstandard, and taking the address like that isn't legal. Are you compiling with warnings and without compiler extensions?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to take the address (or write `void main()`). What's the compiler you are using?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2008. And please note that this code compiles without any error or warning. here is the snapshot of compilation:1>------ Build started: Project: ch, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)
1>ch.cpp
1>Build log was saved at "file://h:\Learning\C++\ch\ch\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>ch - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Just so you know what that error log is *supposed* to look like when sent to a compiler with any sense: [**see it live**](http://ideone.com/o5ufsP)

Comment: I have changed the void main to int main as below even then its working void func1(double *ptr)
{
 cout<<*ptr;
 *ptr=*ptr+2;
}
int main()
{
 const double ab=2;
 func1(&static_cast<double>(ab));
 cout<<ab;
 cin.get();
 return 0;
}

Comment: The ability to use `void main()` is [a Microsoft-specific extension in their Visual C++ compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx). I'm not sure about taking the address of the `static_cast<double>()` bit.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to `void main()`, it is [a Microsoft-specific extension to the Visual C++ compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx).

The `&static_cast<double>()` bit is more puzzling. Interestingly, if you change `double` to `int`s, the Visual C++ compiler (2013) correctly reports an error:

```
#include <iostream>

void func1(int* ptr) 
{
    std::cout << *ptr;
}

int main()
{
    const int ab = 2;
    func1(&static_cast<int>(ab));
    std::cin.get();
}
```

The above code snippet gives:

```
1>  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x64
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>  
1>  main.cpp
1>main.cpp: error C2101: '&' on constant
1>main.cpp: error C2664: 'void func1(int *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int *'
1>          Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

When I replace all instances of `int` (except for `int main()`) with `double` or `float`, amazingly enough it compiles. When done with `int`, `short`, `char`, or `long`, it correctly reports C2101.

Just to explore this further, I've converted your functions into templates:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void func1(T* ptr) 
{
    std::cout << *ptr;
}

template<typename T>
void func0()
{
    const T ab = 2;
    func1<T>(&static_cast<T>(ab));
}
```

And tried calling the following:

```
func0<float>();     // No error
func0<double>();    // No error
func0<char>();      // C2101
func0<int>();       // C2101
func0<short>();     // C2101
func0<long>();      // C2101
func0<long long>(); // C2101
```

The `unsigned` versions of the last 5 also produces C2101 errors. I can reliably reproduce this with Visual C++ 2013. It appears that the error is not given when `T` is a `float` or a `double`. GCC produces compilation errors on all calls to `func0` with:

```
main.cpp:14:18: error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
         func1(&static_cast(ab));
```

This issue reminds me of [a non-standard extension in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zyb9yb4.aspx) that allows you to take an address of a class temporary. So I tried this with a class type:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int) {} // Foo(double) {} does not change the outcome
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo&)
{
    return os;
}
```

When calling `func0<Foo>()`, I get the expected C4238 warning (I always compile with the "Turn warnings into errors" option set):

```
1>  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x64
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>
1>  main.cpp
1>main.cpp: error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>          main.cpp: see reference to function template instantiation 'void func0(void)' being compiled
1>main.cpp: warning C4238: nonstandard extension used : class rvalue used as lvalue
```

Given these results, this makes me think that this is indeed a compiler bug, and even the C++ compiler in VS2013 exhibits this behavior. It may be related to C4238. As T.C. has alluded to in the comments, it may also have to do with the fact that floating point types cannot be used constant expressions. Either way, this is one of the more bizzare bugs I've come across.

Comment: I think this is a compiler bug. Something I noticed though is if I use `func1(&static_cast<int>(ab));` that the VS IDE (2013) highlights a problem with the static_cast by the squiggly underline. If I mouse over static_cast it actually tells me that it is an lvalue error but when compiled it gives no error and produced the output the OP shows

Comment: Yes you are right with int it is giving error but not with double , may be its a compiler bug.

Comment: Interesting, might have something to do with the inability of floating point types to be used in constant expressions.

Comment: Thanks, Elbert Mai, for your valuable inputs

Comment: [It's not a bug. It's a "feature."](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807118/temporary-objects-can-be-bound-to-non-const-references) (or more specifically, an intentional extensions)

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually casting away the `const`, since it's a valid and not a pointer. You're only making a copy of the `double`, which being primitive, is a trivial copy.

Comment: But why the statement  func1(&static_cast<double>(ab)); does not give any error. And also i am able to change the value of ab. Please find below the code void func1(double *ptr)
{
 cout<<*ptr;
 *ptr=*ptr+2;
}
int main()
{
 const double ab=2;
 func1(&static_cast<double>(ab));
 cout<<ab;
 cin.get();
 return 0;
}
The output is 2 4 (note 4 is the modified value after fun1 returns)

Comment: @user1129251 There's no error because of a compiler bug. But even if this code was legal, it'd be giving you the address of the copy of your double. You still aren't modifying `ab` .

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code is not able to do that....it does not compile. I'm getting this error:

> main.cpp:13:32: error: lvalue required as unary & operand

Probably your compiler is too permissive. I tried with GNU GCC version 4.8.1 from http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php

Could way to remove constness is to use `const_cast` (even if it remans not recommended to do this...)

```
void func1(double *ptr) 
{
  cout<<*ptr;
}

int main()
{
   const double ab=2;
   const double* ptr = &ab;
   func1(const_cast<double*>(ptr));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am using visual studio 2008 and its compile successfully please find below the snapshot of compilation report.1>------ Build started: Project: ch, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)
1>ch.cpp
1>Build log was saved at "file://h:\Learning\C++\ch\ch\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>ch - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Visual Studio is often more permissive than GNU compiler....the fact that it compiles does not mean it works...

Comment: It is also working and giving the result.But i think its a compiler bug as explained above by "In silico" in his comments.